# When I try to upgrade to PHP 7.4, it says I already have the newest version... but I don't

Tags: upgrade, php

I have followed these steps...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install php7.4 php7.4-common php7.4-cli
```

Output is...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.4 is already the newest version (7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
php7.4-cli is already the newest version (7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
php7.4-common is already the newest version (7.4.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
...
```

What to do?  In phpinfo() my version is 7.0.  My cli version is 7.2.

UPDATE:

```
# update-alternatives --list php
/usr/bin/php.default
/usr/bin/php7.0
/usr/bin/php7.1
/usr/bin/php7.2
/usr/bin/php7.3
/usr/bin/php7.4
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo update-alternatives --list php`? Please edit your question and add the output to it.

Comment: Why did you add a PPA for this?

Comment: @Jos -- I updated the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the steps I mentioned in my question, it looks like these are the steps I needed to upgrade from php7.0 to php7.4...

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
a2dismod php7.0
a2enmod php7.4
systemctl restart apache2
```